# Operator point (.) in java

Tags: java

I have a program made in Java (not mine) and I'm trying to understand it. But there is something that I don't understand.

This is the part of the code :

```
ModuleAzote m1 = new ModuleAzote(); 
Result r1 = new Result();

m1.resultSimulationHtml = r1;
```

What I don't unserstand is : `m1.resultSimulationHtml`. In the ModuleAzote class, there is no attribut and no method `resultSimulationHtml`. It appears twice in all the class. So I don't know what it is.  If someone can explain me what type of element the operator point(.) refers, it will be so helpful !

Comment: Is your code compiling if resultSimulationHtml is not a field in `ModuleAzote` or in any of its super class?

Comment: @SMA Ok ... I understand now ... I'm so stupid ! Of course, I didn't see the super class ! x) Thanks !

Comment: There is no magic, `.` refers to the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that instance variables are usually `private` (in order to hide them within the class), some classes have variables with `protected` or `public` modifiers. Inheriting from a class means that the subclass has all the variables of its superclass. If you are able to access a variable from outside the class in which it was declared, it is either `protected` or `public`.

Most IDEs will provide a way to view where a variable comes from, including any modifiers it may have. Additionally, the Javadocs may also be a good source of information.